# Background image scrolling using storyboard iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

From past few days i have been trying to achieve scrolling of a background image using storyboard, but couldn't achieve it. If anyone can help me out that is much appreciable. I am attaching a snapshot of my storyboard along with this question if i need to do anything more for your clear understanding please let me know

[image: Scroll view Storyboard]

Comment: pin the height of image equal to the content size of UIScrollView.

Comment: @WannaBeGeek presently i have pinned it to the superview which is view above UIImageView so are you asking me to pin that height now to UIScrollView instead of contentView above UIImageView...?

Comment: Don't fix the height of `View` inside `UIScrollView` and height of `ImageView`. Just pin bottom constraint of `View` with `ScrollView` and bottom constraint of `ImageView` with `View`

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase your content size of UIScrollView and also set the background image having equal size of width and height to ur UIScrollView.